# Navbar font color won't change with onscroll function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Background color changing works fine, but font color won't change. Here's my code":

```
`<div class="navbar-container"></div>
        <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
            <ul class="menu-links1">
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links nav-about">O nama</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links nav-serv">Servisi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links nav-events">Dogadjaji</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="" class="brand-logo"><img src="blndrlogo.png" alt=""></a>
            <ul class="menu-links2">
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links nav-gallery">Galerija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links nav-loc">Lokacija</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="nav-links nav-contact">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
       </nav>
    </div>`
```

here's JavaScript code, i really don't get the point.:((((((((

```
        const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
const navbarText = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links')

window.onscroll = () => {
    if (window.scrollY > 500) {
        navbar.classList.add('nav-active');
        navbarText.classList.add('nav-text-active')
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove('nav-active');
        navbarText.classList.remove('nav-text-active');
    }
};
```

Comment: `navbarText` is not a single Element, it's an `NodeList` . Use loop to add/remove classes from elements one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `for loop` To add a class to a set of elements with a similar class

```
window.onscroll = () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 500) {
    navbar.classList.add('nav-active');
    for (var i = 0; i < navbarText.length; i++) {
      navbarText[i].classList.add('nav-text-active');
    }
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove('nav-active');
    for (var i = 0; i < navbarText.length; i++) {
      navbarText[i].classList.remove('nav-text-active');
    }
  }
};
```